# Do I need WCF layer in the backend layer of my WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I am creating my first stand alone desktop WPF application using Entity Framework. Do I need a WCF layer to access database? Is this a bad practise if I just call DBContext directly from ViewModels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### TL; DR

The short answer is: it depends!

#### The long answer

It depends on your use case you need to implement. If you need to add another layer of abstraction -the WCF layer- to hide your OR/M away you can do it. However if your strategy is easy enough like a standalone WPF application I wouldn't bother making a WCF layer. You can simply access the `IDBContext` in your application, but keep in mind to not tightly couple your viewmodels with EF.

Always worth try keeping the concerns separate!

And these concerns are:

- Data- or Persistence (EF) Models that are used to map your database to your OO models
- ViewModels that are supporting your Views with data to show
- Mapping of your Persistence and ViewModels

This way you can achieve a lightweight setup that aims for better separation and better testing ability.

#### Further Extensibility

Later on your development path, when you arrive at a point where you *need* to add an infrastructural concern like a WCF layer which could serve as a public API -or an entry point- to your shared database access, you can easily add it as a new project, put its classes behind interfaces (these are the only ones you will have as reference added to your WPF project) and let this project have the exact implementations.